# Validators do Pacote l5-repository

Tags: laravel

1º É possível validar utilizando o próprio pacote? Atualmente, eu uso o pacote apenas para retornar as regras, exemplo:

```
Validator::make($data, $this->getRules())->validate();

Onde:

$data:
São os meus dados que vieram do HTML.

$this->getRules()
Esse método getRules retornar minhas regras, é possível informar também se estou criando um dado ou atualizando ($action).
```

2º É possível formatar os dados antes de válida-los?. Quando eu fazia pelo Form Request, eu fazia da seguinte forma, exemplo:

```
public function validationData(){
     $data = $this->all();

     if(array_key_exists('valor_total', $data)){
         if (preg_match("/[,]/", $data['valor_total']) > 0){
            $data['valor_total'] = preg_replace('/[.]/', '', $data['valor_total']);
            $data['valor_total'] = preg_replace('/[,]/', '.', $data['valor_total']);
            $data['valor_total'] = (float)$data['valor_total'];
         }
     }

    $this->getInputSource()->replace($data);
    return $data;
}
```

3º É possível alterar um dado após a validação?. Exemplo, tenho um campo chamado data_nascimento (date) que eu recebo do front-end no formato d/m/Y e na validação eu verifico este mesmo formato, quero que após a validação, formatar para Y-m-d. Eu sei que dá para fazer isso com mutators, mas eu gostaria de fazer isso com o Validate.

4º Como efetuar validações do tipo Unique? Com o Form Request, eu fazia da seguinte forma:

```
public function rules(){
    $id = $this->route('filiai');

    return [
      'matriz_id' => 'required|integer|exists:pessoas_juridicas,id',
      'cnpj' => "required|cnpj|unique:empresas_filiais,cnpj,$id,id",
    ];
}
```

Só que agora com l5-repository, eu não vou ter mais a request, então, como devo efetuar?.

5º Alguém conhece algum projeto (de preferência, com maior número de exemplos reais possíveis) em repositório público para me basear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro crie a classe de validação:

[image: Validator]

Depois no seu repositório registre esse validador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora quando você criar o registro pelo repositório ou fazer update, automaticamente os validadores serão executados.

`$this->attributeRepository->create($data)
$this->attributeRepository->update($data, $id)`

Caso precise executar manualmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre a validação do unique, ele já identificar o atributo unique que você esta criando ou alterando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre alterar os dados antes de inserir no banco de dados pode usar os [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators).